# UIButton IBAction method only drawing to screen once?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I am a little confused about something I was just trying for fun. I have written a little method called `animateBars_V1` which uses an array of UIImageViews and alters the height of each UIImageView to show a changing set of coloured bars.

[image]

```
- (void)animateBars_V1 {
    srandom(time(NULL));
    for(UIImageView *eachImageView in [self barArray]) {
        NSUInteger randomAmount = kBarHeightDefault + (random() % 100);

        CGRect newRect;
        CGRect barRect = [eachImageView frame];

        newRect.size.height = randomAmount;
        newRect.size.width = barRect.size.width;
        newRect.origin.x = barRect.origin.x;
        newRect.origin.y = barRect.origin.y - (randomAmount - barRect.size.height);
        [eachImageView setFrame:newRect];
    }
}
```

This works fine, I then added a UIButton with a UIAction for when the button is pressed. Each time the button is pressed `animateBars_V1` is called and the coloured bars update.

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed {
    for(int counter = 0; counter<5; counter++) {
        [self animateBars_V1];
        NSLog(@"COUNTER: %d", counter);
    }
}
```

My question is just for fun I decided that each time the button is pressed I would call `animateBars_V1` 5 times. What happens is that the bars don't change until after the loop has exited. This results in:

```
Screen as per storyboard
COUNTER: 0
COUNTER: 1
COUNTER: 2
COUNTER: 3
COUNTER: 4
Screen Updates
```

Is this the correct behaviour? I don't need a fix or workaround as this was just for fun, I was more curious what was happening for future reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are calling `animateBars_V1` multiple times within a loop, the frames of the bars do get set multiple times, but before they can be rendered, `animateBars_V1` gets called again, and the frames are set to a new position/size.

The call to render (`drawRect:` and related methods) doesn't occur until after the loop is finished - since it is an IBAction, it is by necessity called in the main thread, which means that all rendering is blocked until the code is completed.

There are of course several solutions to this. A simple method to do the multi-animation thing is to use `UIView animateWithDuration:animations:completion:` in the following manner:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed {
    [self animateBarsWithCount:5];
}

- (void)animateBarsWithCount:(int)count
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.25f animations:^{
        [self animateBars_V1];
    }completion:^(BOOL finished){
        [self animateBarsWithCount:count - 1];
    }];
}

//animateBars_V1 not repeated
```

Of course, if you simply wanted to run the animation one time, (but actually animated) you should do it like this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.25f animations:^{
        [self animateBars_V1];
    } completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that does make sense and I suspected that something like that was happening. I just wanted to be sure I knew why for future reference. Much appreciated ...

Comment: Yes, drawing on iOS is not in "real time," but happens after you "fall out" of your method.

Comment: UIView animateWithDuration:animations:completion: is very interesting, I will certainly add that in.

Answer (score 2):

CrimsonDiego is right

you can try to delay each call with this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed {
    for(int counter = 0; counter<5; counter++) {
        float ii = 1.0 * counter / 10;
        [self performSelector:@selector(animateBars_V1) withObject:nil afterDelay:ii];
        //  [self animateBars_V1];
        NSLog(@"COUNTER: %d", counter);
    }
}
```

Comment: `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` is also a perfectly valid method to do this by. It lacks the animated effect if used alone, but it can be used in many more situations than just animation.

Comment: Just a quick question if I may, performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: works in this situation because by the time it "performs the selector" the method -(IBAction)buttonPressed has long since exited and is not blocking the main thread?

Comment: basically yes, it works because it runs "animateBars_V1" in 5 new threads, and the main thread redraws the dimensions as it found them, as the last executed "animateBars_V1" set them

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
for(int counter = 0; counter<5; counter++) {
    [self animateBars_V1];
    NSLog(@"COUNTER: %d", counter);
}
```

This for loop is executed in nano seconds and your eye is not able to catch up that change as eye can detect only 1/16th of a second.
For testing what can run this code in a timer that runs five time.

**Edited**
Removed sleep call as it will sleep the main thread and everything will stop. So use Timer here

Comment: not a matter of eyes velocity: Xcode just doesn't draw it for each loop, it just sets some variables and then it draws just the last variables value at the end of the thread

Comment: @meronix button actions are triggered on main thread unless you explicitly call that method from a background thread.

Comment: right... but isn't the redraw screen shown just at the end of the thread? if not, you should see something if you use a loop of more than 5 (a.g. 500000)... the eye is slower, but you shoud notice a sort of flash, not just a delay in the execution of your code...

Comment: That's what I'm saying if you use a loop larger (as you suggested 500000) we will watch flickers it means that code is updating frame continuously. It's not waiting for the thread to complete.

Comment: i didn't tried the code, but i don't think we will get flickers... did you tried?

Comment: :( nope I didn't. But I'm sure code will update the frame with waiting to end the thread.

Comment: Had another look this morning and I don't think it does update the screen until - (IBAction)buttonPressed exits. I could be wrong about this and would be interested to hear if anyone knows otherwise, but from what I have seen I am not seeing any flickering to imply that the screen is being updated (in a fashion that is too quick to see) during the method.